# Reading large files with PHP line by line?

Tags: php, file

I have done a research and on many places it is mentioned to use fgets(). Ok, but I need to set a limit of bytes to read and there is no way I can be sure my line will not be longer than the limit I have set. Am I right and is there another solution?

My only another idea is to use fgetc() but there must be a better solution...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php):

> Reading ends when `length - 1` bytes have been read, or a newline (which is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first). **If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.**

Comment: It's right there in the documentation. It's almost like the documentation was never even looked at.  >:\

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at some old tutorial where it said the default length is 1024.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not a good idea to use fgetc function on large files
a) It will be slower
b) You ought to handle everything manually, this leads to bugs (e.g. different line endings)

As for original task, sometimes it worth converting your input to another format, that is good for fast reading. For example, split extra long lines if it is possible.